# How do extensions override non-rewritable classes

Tags: extensions, overrides

I was going to put together a tiny extension to enable [Template hints under global scope](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/695/template-hints-under-global-scope/699#699), but got stuck trying to rewrite `core/template`.

Class rewrites only work for classes instantiated via one of Magento's methods to do so (`helper`, `getModel`, `getSingleton`). For abstract and heavily-extended-from classes you seem to be left with the option of `local/Mage` overrides.

Two questions:

1. Is there a smart way to avoid `local/Mage` overrides at all times?
2. If there isn't, how do you go about including such overrides in community extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Any extension which you offer to the community should be under the community code pool.

2) You shouldn't, but you can, and sometimes you must because [Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) has been ignored a lot in Magento 1.

There is almost always a way around the need to override, including the use of Reflection [as mentioned by Vinai awhile back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201013/833795).

If there is too much downside to workarounds, you simply must take ownership of the class definition. You can do one of the following, provided that users are made aware:

1. In the community code pool, provide the modified definition under Mage | Varien | Zend namespace as appropriate. Possible concern would be that end user might have done the same.
2. As above, but in a new code pool: prepend the new codepool to the bootstrapped include paths using `set_include_path()`. Drawback: more `stat()`ing caused by the autoloader, and your include path manipulation will be non-obvious as it is outside of the bootstrap.
3. If possible, provide the definition yourself before it is loaded from its normal location, e.g. by explicitly `include()`ing it from a non-standard location under your namespace.

Sound your case-by-case needs out here - someone will have an idea. As for the template path hints in the admin scope, [see my answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/732/5) which doesn't even require PHP.

Comment: `community` code pool of course. Say in this case really need to override `Mage_Core_Block_Template` to make a slight change to the way hints are prepended to blocks.

Comment: ...a perfect example of "there's another way"! In this case it would be far more preferable to make use of the [`core_block_abstract_to_html_after` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L886) event, [just like Fabrizio Branca is doing in his AOE_TemplateHints module](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_TemplateHints/blob/master/app/code/community/Aoe/TemplateHints/etc/config.xml#L27).

Comment: Awesome, great piece of advice! Cheers